# Manage views hierarchy in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Exist in SwiftUI the equivalent of following UIKit methods?

```
view.addSubview(aView)
view.removeFromSuperview()
view.bringSubviewToFront(aView)
view.sendSubviewToBack(aView)
```

Basically, I need to remove myView from oldSuperView, add it to newSuperView and bring to the front a childView already present in newSuperView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No equivalent. Because every time you change a state, the view is build again entirely. You can use `if/else` or etc to `hide/show` or even add or not add a view, but you can't add or remove without refreshing the view.

One thing you can do is to encapsulate the view you want to add or remove it's subviews and change it's state instead of it's superview. So changes will apply internally.

Comment: I need something like tabview content, they can keep scroll state so that onAppear will be trigger. Do you know how to do that? I am using zindex but could not trigger onAppear event and scroll state